# git pull VS git pull --no-rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

What is the difference between `git pull` and `git pull --no-rebase`
?

In my understanding the git pull by default does a fetch then a merge. So the no-rebase means merge and therefore these two commands are exactly identical! Is that correct?

Comment: Not identical when you have `pull.rebase` set to `true` in config.

Comment: @RomainValeri you could make that an answer... (AFAIK it's *the* answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have `pull.rebase` set to `true` in your config, the default action upon `git pull` is a rebase.

In **this** case, the `--no-rebase` option is a one-time exception to your personal default, resulting in a merge-pull.

Comment: Ok, but if I left the default settings these two commands are strictly identical?

Comment: @JeanDujardin In this context yes they are.